# Unable to find outside of range value using R tool

Tags: r, statistics

1. Generate 500 random numbers between 0 to 100.
2. Find the sum of these 500 random numbers.
3. Repeat steps 1) and 2) above 1000 times by generating new set of random numbers.
4. Assuming Y denote the sum of 500 numbers, obtain Box-Whisker plot of random variable Y.
5. Display values of Y which are outside mean +/- 2 *SD where SD is standard deviation.
6. Which statistical distribution is justified for random variable Y.

For

```
y <- runif(500, min = 1, max = 100) # 1
sum(y) # 2

c <- runif(1000, min = 1, max = 100) # 3
sum(c) # 4
```

Above mention i manage to figure out answer, but not sure whether it is correct or not.
Please help me out.

Comment: Your step 3 isn't what was asked. You have to repeat step 1) and 2). And your min-value has to be `0` not `1`

Comment: You may find the function  `replicate` useful. and it is always worth checking out what makes a good question on SO at [MRE]

Comment: Thank you for answer @MartinGal; (1) need 500 random variables (rv)  between 0 to 100 i.e. Uniform distribution (2) sum of 500 rv..it should be a single value (3) I guess it required more than 1000 RV and then need to sum it...but what I need more is of question no (5)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a homework task, but let me try to point you to the right direction.

Step 1. - 3. is creating the sum of random variables. Since there is no distribution given, we assume uniform distribution.

```r
Y <- numeric(0)  # sums are stored here
for (i in 1:1000) {
    Y[i] <- sum(runif(500, min=0, max=100))
}
```

So `Y` contains 1000 sums of 500 uniform distrubuted random variables.

There is another way to create this `Y`:

```r
Y <- sapply(1:1000, function(x) sum(runif(500, min=0, max=100)))
```

For steps 4 to 6 I assume you take a look at the R help for box plots (step 4/5) and histogramms (step 6). Try `?boxplot` and `?hist`.

```r
Y <- replicate(1000, sum(runif(500, min=0, max=100)))

min_val = mean(Y) - 2*sd(Y)
max_val = mean(Y) + 2*sd(Y)

Y_min <- Y[Y < min_val]
Y_max <- Y[Y > max_val]

boxplot(Y, range=1)
points(rep(1,length(Y_min)), Y_min, pch=23, col="red")
points(rep(1,length(Y_max)), Y_max, pch=23, col="blue")
```

You get an answer for step 6 if you understand the mathmatics. Perhaps a central limit theorem gives you some insight.

Comment: Thank you for feedback, but it is giving the value of higher than 100, where its value should be specifically between 0 - 100; I have made boxplot, but moreover, I am unable to get Y value of outside mean +/- 2SD

Comment: Do you want to know the values `mean(Y) + 2*sd(Y)`? Or do you want to plot them?

Comment: Nope? Your task was creating 500 random numbers between 0 and 100. Assuming those random numbers are uniform distributed, the sum of those 500 random numbers is about 25.000.

Comment: I need syntax for question no 5...unable to find it

Comment: usally "unable to find it" isn't enough. Give some examples what you tried, describe your way of solving the problem. I edited my post, everything you need is there.